# Does function pointer need parethesis in c?

Tags: c, function-pointers, language-design

From this question [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work), I tried it here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a, int b){ return a+b; }

int add2(int(*fp)(int,int)){
    return fp(2,3);
}

int (*factory(int n))(int,int){
    printf("got params:%i\n",n);
    return add;
}

int main(){
    int *p(int,int) = factory(5); // it has to be (*p)
    printf("%i\n",p(1,2));
}
```

There was mentioned

> the standard says that a function name is
> converted to the address of the function

So it should work without the parethesis anyway, when it is converted to address.

But it gives error:

```
function ‘p’ is initialized like a variable
```

But is should be function *pointer*, not just function. So how is it with the syntax?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that

```
int *p(int,int)
```

declares p as a [function (int, int) returning a pointer to an int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+*p%28int%2Cint%29).

You need

```
int (*p)(int,int)
```

which declares p as a [pointer to a function (int, int) returning an int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*p%29%28int%2Cint%29)

Comment: This is why I like declaring the first variant as `int* p(int, int)`, which *removes all doubt* (despite most of my colleagues protestations to the contrary).

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's misleading to write `int*`.  It's contrary to the syntactic precedence.  It implies that `int` and `*` bind more tightly than `*` and the declarator, which is untrue.  Experienced C programmers know that primaries bind more tightly than unary operators, so `int *p(int, int)` is perfectly clear, and is equivalent to `int *(p(int, int))`.  Declarator syntax matches use syntax.  Also `int *p, *q;` is *much* clearer than `int* p, *q;`, which is truly misleading and strongly suggests that `q` is `int **` rather than `int *`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler emits error on your code - so the code is **invalid**.

`int *p(int, int);` - declares the function returning pointer

`int (*p)(int, int);` - defines pointer to the function.

You can use typedefs to use "usual pointer syntax:

```
typedef int functype(int, int);

functype *p; // defines the function pointer `p`
```

BTW your example will be easier to read when we use `typedef`s

```
typedef int func(int, int);

int add(int a, int b){ return a+b; }

int add2(func *funcptr){
    return funcptr(2,3);
}

func *factory(int n){
    printf("got params:%i\n",n);
    return add;
}

int main(){
    func *funcptr = factory(5); 
    printf("%i\n",funcptr(1,2));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zj4Yax

Comment: @RobertHarvey *`you obfuscate your`* you are just not familiar with this form.

Comment: I don't think it's clearer at all.  That typedef will only work with a function taking two int parameters, and there's nothing in the typedef'd name that would suggest this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I do not understand you comment. I believe that is related to my previous comment. Functions always (except some weird `int f() ...` take well defined number of parameters (even variadic functions which are well defined). If you need another - define another function type.

Comment: [ shrug ] Function pointers aren't *that* hard to understand that you need to typedef them to make them "simpler."

Comment: @RobertHarvey sure this is a perfect example of the "not obfuscating" "plain" function pointer syntax : `int  (*(*func[5])(float, int (*)()))(int);` very easy to humans for sure

Comment: even `cdecl` has a problem to translate it to English. But it is the correct C code : https://godbolt.org/z/qfM8nf

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
// A normal function with an int parameter 
// and void return type 
void p(int a) 
{ 
    printf("Value of a is %d\n", a); 
} 
  
int main() 
{ 
    // fun_ptr is a pointer to function p()  
    void (*fun_ptr)(int) = &p; 
  
    /* The above line is equivalent of following two 
       void (*fun_ptr)(int); 
       fun_ptr = &p;  
    */
  
    // Invoking p() using fun_ptr 
    (*fun_ptr)(10); 
  
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int *p(int,int) = factory(5);
```

This doesn't work because `int *p(int,int)` here means a function declaration that takes two `int` and returns a pointer to int. It's similar to when you write `int* p(int,int);`. It's not a function pointer.

You do need the bracket:

```
int (*p)(int,int) = factory(5); // this declare `p` as a function pointer, then assign it to `factory` function.
```

Answer (score 0):

A function name is indeed converted to the address of the function, which is why you don't need (but can have) `&` in `return add;`.

However, `int (*p)(int,int) = factory(5);` absolutely does need the first pair of parentheses because otherwise (`int *p(int,int)`) you're declaring `p` as a function taking two `int` and returning a pointer to `int`, not as a pointer to a function taking two `int`s and returning `int`.